# Rank of matrix without echelon form

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to compute the rank of the following matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1\ 1\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0\\
0\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 0\\
0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 1\ 1\\
1\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 0\\
0\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 0\\
0\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 1\\
1\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 1\\
0\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 0\\
0\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 0\\
0\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 0\\
0\ 1\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0\\
0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 0\ 1\ 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Is there a fast way to do it without reducing to row echelon form?

Comment: Is this some arbitrary matrix, or did it come from somewhere?

Comment: Rank of given matrix is ≥4. This is clearly visible (from 4th entry of first column, 5th entry of second column and 6th entry of third column it is clear that first three columns are linearly independent. further, from second entry of 4th column it is clear that, 4th column does not belongs to span of first three and hence first four columns are linearly independent)

Comment: Row reduction is fast especially for $0-1$ matrices. To make it faster, take the transpose and then perform row operations; or what amounts to the same thing, perform column operations instead. The rank is the same in both cases.